# How to validate inputs with 2 messages?python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have the example for gross pay but I want don't accept any string value . I tried to solve it with while true statement but executed with the first question of code.

I want these outputs :

Enter the hours worked this week:asd

please integer number

Enter the hours worked this week:10

Enter the hourly pay rate :asd

please float number

Enter the hourly pay rate :20.01

anyone help

my code

while True:

```
       try:

           hours = int(input('Enter the hours worked this week: '))

           pay_rate = float(input('Enter the hourly pay rate: '))

           gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

           print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'))

       except ValueError:

                        print('please integer number)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a function I generally use when I need to validate multiple user input and request different types.

```
def get_input(typ, msg, err):
    while True:
        try:
            return typ(input(msg))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter {0}".format(err))


hours = get_input(int, 'Enter the hours worked this week: ', 'an intger number')
pay_rate = get_input(float, 'Enter the hourly pay rate: ', 'a float number')
gross_pay = hours * pay_rate
print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'))
```

Comment: Thanks Steven , this code help me because I am a beginner to learn python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def hoursGet():
    hours = input("Enter the hours worked this week: ")
    try:
        hours = int(hours)
        return hours
    except ValueError:
        print ("please integer number")
        hoursGet()
```

and simply write other functions for the other questions, substituting the `print`ed statements and the data types.

Comment: At the end, just call all of the functions in the order that you want them, and it should work properly.

Comment: Thanks Sid , when to run your code . it is not accept string value but not ask me again the same question just moved to second question.